# Visual Studio performance testing on opening a Word doc

Tags: performance, testing

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to create a web performance test on how long does it take to open a Word doc. I recorded the test as usual and ran successfully, but I am not sure if the test did exactly what I wanted it to do. Anyone has experience in that?

Also, what if I would the program to click on a word doc randomly every time I ran it? Is that achievable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if the test did exactly what I wanted it to do.

To be sure create two Word files with the different sizes, e.g. 100 KB and 10 MB. Then run your tests on both files. First time should be quite less then second one. If so your tests are correct in first approximation.

> Also, what if I would the program to click on a word doc randomly every time I ran it? Is that achievable?

If 'randomly' means click on the random area on the document, then you better use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which is allows you to simulate mouse moving and clicking.